# RSpec and Rails 3 - Simple tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

RSpec 2.5, Rails 3.0.6 - git://github.com/stevecastaneda/project.git

I'm doing a few simple tests to make sure users are valid when registering.  The test that is failing is "should require username".  The resulting error is:

```
Failure/Error: new_user(:username => '').should have(1).error_on(:username)
       expected 1 error on :username, got 0
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe User do
  def new_user(attributes = {})
    attributes[:username] ||= 'foo'
    attributes[:email] ||= 'foo@example.com'
    attributes[:password] ||= 'abc123'
    attributes[:password_confirmation] ||= attributes[:password]
    User.new(attributes)
  end

  before(:each) do
    User.delete_all
  end

  it "should be valid" do
    new_user.should be_valid
  end

  it "should require username" do
    new_user(:username => '').should have(1).error_on(:username)
  end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # new columns need to be added here to be writable through mass assignment
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :prepare_password

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, :allow_blank => true
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-\w\._@]+$/i, :allow_blank => true, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .-_@"
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true

  # login can be either username or email address
  def self.authenticate(login, pass)
    user = find_by_username(login) || find_by_email(login)
    return user if user && user.password_hash == user.encrypt_password(pass)
  end

  def encrypt_password(pass)
    BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(pass, password_salt)
  end

  private

  def prepare_password
    unless password.blank?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = encrypt_password(password)
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm simply creating a new user (not using factories just yet, just simple tests) with an empty username and because of `validates_presence_of :username` it should have errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: Weird... your code (copy and pasted exactly) works great for me on Rails 3.0.7 and Rspec 2.5.0...

Comment: Updated to 3.0.7 and nada.  This is driving me nuts!

Comment: What do you get when you clone/test this project? git://github.com/stevecastaneda/project.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Mocha for your mock framework, you  need to tell Rspec this (just putting Mocha in your `Gemfile` won't be enough). In your `spec_helper.rb` file, change this:

```
config.mock_with :rspec
```

To this:

```
config.mock_with :mocha
```

and all of your tests will pass.

---

**More Info:**

Your `User` model spec is actually working perfectly fine, if you run it by itself:

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

Your `UsersController` spec is actually the one interfering, which is why running `rspec` for your entire project fails.

Your controller specs run before your model specs. In your controller specs, you have a couple `User.any_instance.stub...` calls. Your very last `UsersController` spec stubs `valid?` to be true. These are not scoped only for your controller specs. Once you hit your `User` model spec, calls to `valid?` still return true because of this stubbing, since Rspec doesn't know you're using Mocha.

Comment: Ah! Totally forgot to change to Mocha.  Thanks! Thanks for explaining the stubbing problem from the Users controller.  I didn't know that those stubs carry over into my model specs like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
user = new_user(:username => '')
user.should_not be_valid
```

Otherwise the validation is not performed, and, therefor, there're no errors.

Works for me:

```
require 'active_model'

def new_user(attributes = {})
  attributes[:username] ||= 'foo'
  attributes[:email] ||= 'foo@example.com'
  attributes[:password] ||= 'abc123'
  attributes[:password_confirmation] ||= attributes[:password]
  User.new(attributes)
end

class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :username, :email

  validates_presence_of :username
end

describe User do
  it "should validate" do
    new_user(:username => '').should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Change this:

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-\w\._@]+$/i, :allow_blank => true, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .-_@"
```

to this:

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-\w\._@]+$/i, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .-_@", :unless => lambda {|u| u.username.blank?}
```

Comment: Still not working.  "expected valid? to return false, got true".  I'm stumped!

Comment: Probably something that you do in your callbacks, etc. Update the answer, validation works for me.

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for your help.  Hrm - what if the validates presence of is being overwritten by allow_blank?  A username of '' isn't empty, right?  Update: Changing to false on the allow_blanks does not change the test outcome.

Comment: Instead of allow_blank on validates_format add :if => lambda{|user| !user.username.blank?}

Comment: Still not working.  I'm going to push this to a public repo so someone can clone and see if it's something somewhere else.  Will update by tomorrow.

Comment: Check it out: git://github.com/stevecastaneda/project.git - Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit, actually, is your users_controller_spec, and the line is:

```
User.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
```

Comment: Thanks! With dmarkow's explanation I can see how this caused issues.  This is a generated authentication through Ryan Bates's nifty-generator tool so I didn't snap to switch to Mocha per his specifications.